# QLPreviewController with navigation buttons

Tags: xcode, button, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm using a Quick Look Class object in order to preview documents in my app.

In some applications I've see that have a toolbar with buttons to navigate across the doc pages, go to first and last pages.

Is this possible using a QLPreview object?

And if it's possible how can implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing the navigation arrows that lets the user switch among different items. Here's a snippet from QLPreviewController's documentation:

> To use a Quick Look preview controller, you must provide a data source object. The data source provides preview items to the controller and tells it how many items to include in a preview navigation list. If there is more than one item in the list, a modally-presented (that is, full-screen) controller displays navigation arrows to let the user switch among the items. For a Quick Look preview controller pushed using a navigation controller, you can provide buttons in the navigation bar for moving through the navigation list.